# Azure Graph API list users in child groups

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a group called "Building Residents". In that group I have 2 groups for every apartment:

```
- Apt1a_Renters
- Apt1a_Owners

- Apt2a_Renters
- Apt2a_Owners
```

etc, etc...

A Person can be in the Apt2a_Owners group but also in the Apt1a_Renters group.

I want to query all members of the "Building Residents" group for users but when I do that, I just get back the groups inside of it.

Is there any way, using a single query, to list all the building residents without bringing back duplicates (same person in apt2a_owners and apt1a_renters)?

Comment: Could you please specify your question? What have you already tried? Are you talking about using the Azure Graph REST API, or any wrapper?

Comment: @JanKruse My question is the last sentence my post (ends in a question mark). I have tried querying the members of the "Building Residents" group (as specified in the sentence before that). I am talking about the Azure Graph API (as specified in the title).

Comment: Do you try to query the API via REST or do you use a wrapper like the C# libraries? I don't understand the structure of your data you're trying to describe. Is it about AAD groups, Office 365 groups, Security groups? Do I understand right: you want all AAD user objects, that are member of the group "Building Residents"? Could you provide sample data, your queries you already tried and the corresponding API responses?

Comment: @JanKruse - I am not using any wrappers or libraries, yet. Right now, I am just using graphexplorer and postman (rest api directly). When I query for members of the "Building Residents" group, like this: https://graph.windows.net/{my_ord}/groups/{obj_id}/$links/members?api-version=1.6, it returns group object IDs, not member IDs. I then have to go into each group and query that group. I just want all the users listed in all child groups from querying the top level group. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Now I understand :-) I don't think the REST API is powerful enough to do that job. But using the C# wrapper and LINQ it should be very easy to put that into one line of code - assuming you are going to use C# - but nevertheless it will end up sending multiple request to the API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Graph REST only can get the direct members from one group. To get the member users recursively, we need to implement it ourselves. Here is a code sample wiring with C# using the Azure AD Graph library for your reference:

```
public void testGetMembersRecursively()
{
    var accessToken="";
    var tenantId="";
    var groupName="";
    var client = GraphHelper.CreateGraphClient(accessToken,tenantId);
    var group = (Group)client.Groups.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.First(g => g.DisplayName ==groupName);
    var groupFetcher = client.Groups.GetByObjectId(group.ObjectId);
    List<string> users = new List<string>();
    GetMembersRecursively(groupFetcher, users);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", users.Distinct<string>().ToArray()));
}

public void GetMembersRecursively(Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IGroupFetcher groupFetcher, List<string> users)
{
    var membersResoult = groupFetcher.Members.ExecuteAsync().Result;
    AddMember( membersResoult, users);

    while (membersResoult.MorePagesAvailable)
    {
        membersResoult = membersResoult.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
        AddMember(membersResoult, users);
    }
}

public void AddMember( IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> membersResoult, List<string> users)
{
    var members = membersResoult.CurrentPage;

    foreach (var obj in members)
    {
        var _user = obj as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User;
        if (_user != null)
            users.Add(_user.DisplayName);
        else
        {
            var groupMember = obj as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group;
            if (groupMember != null)
            {
                GetMembersRecursively(GetGroupById(groupMember.ObjectId), users);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GraphHelper class:

```
class GraphHelper
{
    public static ActiveDirectoryClient CreateGraphClient(string accessToken, string tenantId)
    {
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

        Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
        Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

        return activeDirectoryClient;
    }    
}
```